# How to get last 3 weeks date range using moment ?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I need date range of last 3 weeks including current week date range.

Ex: today's date is : 31/08/2018

output will be :

`Aug 26 - Sep 01 , 
 Aug 19 - Aug 25 , 
 Aug 12 - Aug 18`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you check the [documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/)?

Comment: @Andreas I has tried using loop of 21 times and increment by 7. But it's more complected. I need easy way to fetch date range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the start of the week using [`.startOf('week')`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/).

```js
var currentWeek = getWeekRange(0);
var lastWeek = getWeekRange(-1);
var weekBeforeLast = getWeekRange(-2);

var currentWeek2 = getWeekRange2(0);

console.log(currentWeek, lastWeek, weekBeforeLast, currentWeek2);

function getWeekRange(week = 0) {
  var weekStart = moment().add(week, 'weeks').startOf('week');
  
  return [...Array(7)].map((_, i) => 
    weekStart.clone().add(i, 'day').format('DD/MM/YYYY')
  );
}

function getWeekRange2(week = 0) {
 var weekStart = moment().add(week, 'weeks').startOf('week');
 var days = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
   days.push(weekStart.clone().add(i, 'day').format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
 }
 return days;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
```

---

For clarification:

`[...Array(7)]` was used for brevity. It's creating an `Array` with 7 `undefined` items, i.e. `[undefined, undefined, ...]`. These items are treated as placeholder and will be mapped out into the days of the week using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Despite being `undefined`, I use the item's `index` within the array to increment the day of the week -- in other words, the first item of the array, `[undefined]`, would have an `index` of `0`, so we would add `0` days, and add until the end of the week.

You could also do something like:

```
function getWeekRange(week = 0) {
  var weekStart = moment().add(week, 'weeks').startOf('week');
  var days = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    days.push(weekStart.clone().add(i, 'day').format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
  }
  return days;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. Can you please explain return [...Array(7)].map((_, i) => line of code ?

Comment: @SachinShah sure thing, I just updated my answer. Please let me know if you have any questions/concerns.

Comment: This is awesome answer. And using that I am able to get weeks data. I have just execute getWeekRange2() 3 times with (0, -1 , -2) params respectively. And I got all dates. Thank you for your answer. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
moment().range(moment().subtract(3, 'weeks'), moment());

moment().subtract(3, 'weeks') this line will return the time before 3 weeks, moment() will return time now and range() will take the range from those two.
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: For that should I have to install npm i moment-range ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 let startOfWeek = moment().subtract(1, 'weeks').startOf('week').toDate().toISOString();
 let endOfWeek = moment().subtract(1, 'weeks').endOf('week').toDate().toISOString();
 console.log(startOfWeek, endOfWeek)
```